# How to display UIImage in UINavigationBar programmatically in UIViewController

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to add `UINavigationBar` programmatically. It is adding successfully. And after that I want to add a `UIImage` into the `UINavigationBar`. It is not displayed however. And also, how can I add text programmatically in `UINavigationBar`?

This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];     
    [self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];

    self.navigationItem.titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logoicon.png"]];
}
```

Comment: Any body help me please........

Comment: I update my answer please try now

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `items` of the navigation bar. Usually this is done by the navigation controller but in this case you own the navigation bar so you need to do it manually:

```
naviBarObj.items = @[ self.navigationItem ];
```

If you want both an image and text in the middle of the navigation bar then you need to create a `UIView` and add both a `UIImageView` and a `UILablel` to it, then add that view as the `titleView`.

Comment: thanks for your response brother.yes i want to add both text and image in center position.How can i do this.please help me

Comment: Try creating a `UIView` and adding both `UIImageView` and a `UILabel` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the **navigation** and **status** bar background only in iOS7. For this, you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_bg.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

The size of the *nav_bg.png* should be **320*64 px**

If you want to simply change the color of navigation bar you can use

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

And for the title in Navigation bar, you should use

```
self.navigationItem.title = @"title";
```

Comment: Is that patch is not changing the image or color of `navigation bar`?

Answer (score 0):

Text with alignment center

```
  UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] ;
  label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20.0];
  label.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.5];
  label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
                   // ^-Use UITextAlignmentCenter for older SDKs.
  label.textColor = [UIColor yellowColor]; // change this color
  self.navigationItem.titleView = label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
       [super viewDidLoad];
        UINavigationBar *naviBarObj = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];     
        [self.view addSubview:naviBarObj];

    UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 120, 44)];
    titleView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"logoicon.png"];
   [naviBarObj addSubview:titleView];
}
```

Try this then you add title view in self navigationBar not in your navigation bar. I edit my ans please try now.

Comment: @Tamilking thanks for your response.But it is not working.getting error like "navigationitemnotfound"

Comment: @Tamilking i got error this line of code like "  [naviBarObj addSubView:titleView];"

Comment: [naviBarObj addSubview:titleView]; change lik this and run

Answer (score 0):

**To add the UIImage(logo image not background image) programmatically in navigationBar**

```
UIImage *imgHome = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
UIImageView *imgvW = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 0, 100, 40)];
imgvW.image = imgHome;
[self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:imgvW];
```

**OR**

```
UIImageView *titleView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"]];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleView];
```